# LINQ complains that subquery returned more than 1 row

Tags: c#, linq

Simple code that pulls a single record ( it's single because the primary key is an int set as an autonumber ):

```
using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
    var record = db.Projects.Single(x => x.ProjectID == projectID);
    record.Deleted = true;
    record.DeletedByUserID = MySession.Current.UserID;
    record.DeletedOn = DateTime.Now;
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I'm not sure why but in some cases as soon as it hits `db.SubmitChanges()` we get an exception stating that `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

But when I "Watch" the record I only am getting back one record.  What could be causing this?

Comment: PS: `FirstOrDefault` has the same issue...

Comment: Try looking at [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861749/sqlexception-because-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value)

Comment: It looks like LINQ TO SQL, right? Is there any particular reason to use it instead of EF? I've never saw such problem there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help to use `db.Projects.First(x => x.ProjectID == projectID);`instead of Single.

It even seems to be a common problem: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/afb292ca-3a61-4a60-8e18-830b92489016/method-single-not-supported-by-linq-to-entities?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Way to solve, don't know if it helps but it's from above link:

```
    public static TElement Single<TElement>
      (this IQueryable<TElement> query)
{
    if (query.Count() != 1)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
    return query.First();
}



// Use it like this

Product prod = (from p in db.Product
                where p.ProductID == 711
                select p).Single();
```

Comment: I updated the answer, it appears to be a known problem with Linq & EF

Comment: This doesnt `var record = (from p in db.Projects
                                                    where p.ProjectID == projectID
                                                    select p).Single();
                                    //var record = db.Projects.First(x => x.ProjectID == projectID);
                                    record.Deleted = true;
                                    record.DeletedByUserID = MySession.Current.UserID;
                                    record.DeletedOn = DateTime.Now;
                                    db.SubmitChanges();`

Comment: Sorry comment came out all wrong, it didnt help I tried to change it to a select... and perform the update but it still is the same result...

Comment: Are you doing this thing in a loop or doing something other changes to the context that will be save on `SubmitChanges()`?

Comment: Im not doing anything to the context except updating those 3 fields record.Deleted, record.DeletedByUserID, and record.DeletedOn.

Comment: Can you log the query? Use [DataContext.Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

That thing

```
db.Projects.Single()
```

means that should be 100%  only 1 value to return and there are many.

In that case use

```
db.Projects.FirstOrDefault()
```

Or what is better check your data or select conditions.

[Enumerable.Single Method (IEnumerable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And about this ... "But when I "Watch" the record I only am getting back one record. What could be causing this?"

Just check your table to see if you have duplicated entries or if you populate in other way your data context use `db.Projects()` to get all records and check it.

Comment: See my comments firstordefault does the same thing.

Comment: Bad idea to use `FirstOrDefault()` because that's only hiding the fact that you have duplicate data. `Single()` is good in this case because it will alert you to the fact that you have an issue somewhere that is allowing duplicate product ids to be persisted.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan Im not using FirstOrDefault, Im just mentioning that if I did use that its still the same issue.

Comment: That's not a correct answer. Both `SingleOrDefault()` and `FirstOrDefault()` return a single record. The only difference is that if there are several records matching the condition, `FirstOrDefault()` returns the first one of them, while `SingleOrDefault()` throws an exception.